# Laravel 5.2 frequently logging out

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. with session driver set to FILE in `.env` file.

I am logging out of the system about every 2 hours, especially when I return from PayPal payment page to my website.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: why don't you check the session settings? you're probably not "logging out", your session is getting expired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set your config settings of timeout from 120 to 2400. this is in minutes.

in config/session.php 'lifetime' => 120 // This is in minutes

Comment: in config/session.php   'lifetime' => 120  // This is in minutes

Answer (score 3):

You can find session configuration in `config/session.php` file.

Change `lifetime` parameter value. You may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires.

```
'lifetime' => 120  // This is in minutes
```