# How to refresh token using Satellizer and interceptors?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, jwt, satellizer

I'm using Satellizer for my angular app, however when the token expires it does not include the `Authorization` header anymore to the `$http` requests resulting to incorrect http error status returned.

How do I handle this and refresh my token? I have already done the interception when `$http` error occurs, my problem is mostly with the refreshing.

I am using Laravel 5.2 and tymon/jwt-auth for my backend.

Comment: Take a look at what I just commented here on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/44054209/3332734