# How to store token in Local or Session Storage in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I want to use Local or session storage to save authentication token in **`angular 2.0.0.`** I  use **`angular2-localstorage`** but it works only **angular 2.0.0-rc.5** and when I used it in 2.0.0 it through me **Type** error. I want to use default local storage of Angular 2.0.0.

Comment: Check out [Angular 2 Cool Storage](https://github.com/Hacklone/angular2-cool-storage)

Comment: Is it best way to store in local storage?

Answer (score 101):

Save to local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: name }));
```

Load from local storage

```
var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
var token = currentUser.token; // your token
```

For more I suggest you go through this tutorial: [Angular 2 JWT Authentication Example & Tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial)

Comment: If I type in  `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token` I can see the token in console. How can I avoid this in production ?

Comment: @Zaker Don't store your token in local storage.

Comment: @Archibald Can you please suggest me where to store the token. Any link describing will also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Use cookies for that, with the `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flags: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: @Zaker If the browser ever has the token, then it is never safe from the user. The only thing you can do is never send anything to the browser you wouldn't want the user to see. That's different than preventing a XSS.

Answer (score 34):

That totally depends of what do you need exactly.
If you just need to store and retrieve a token in order to use it in your http requests, 
i suggest you to simply create a service and use it in your whole project.

example of basic integration:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular@core'

@Injectable()
export class TokenManager {

    private tokenKey:string = 'app_token';

    private store(content:Object) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey, JSON.stringify(content));
    }

    private retrieve() {
        let storedToken:string = localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);
        if(!storedToken) throw 'no token found';
        return storedToken;
    }

    public generateNewToken() {
        let token:string = '...';//custom token generation;
        let currentTime:number = (new Date()).getTime() + ttl;
        this.store({ttl: currentTime, token});
    }

    public retrieveToken() {

        let currentTime:number = (new Date()).getTime(), token = null;
        try {
            let storedToken = JSON.parse(this.retrieve());
            if(storedToken.ttl < currentTime) throw 'invalid token found';
            token = storedToken.token;
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        return token;

    }

}
```

However if you need to use the local storage more often, by using the stored values in your app views for example. 
You can use one of the libraries that provides a wrapper of the webstorages like you did with angular2-localstorage.

I created some months ago [ng2-webstorage](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage) that should respond to your needs.
It provides two ng2 services and two decorators to sync the webstorage's values and the service/component's attributes.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalStorageService, LocalStorage} from 'ng2-webstorage';

@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `
        <section>{{boundValue}}</section>
        <section><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="attribute"/></section>
        <section><button (click)="saveValue()">Save</button></section>
    `,
})
export class FooComponent {

    @LocalStorage()
    boundValue; // attribute bound to the localStorage
    value;

    constructor(private storage:LocalStorageService) {
        this.localSt.observe('boundValue')// triggers the callback each time a new value is set
            .subscribe((newValue) => console.log('new value', newValue));
    }

    saveValue() {
      this.storage.store('boundValue', this.value); // store the given value
    }

}
```

Answer (score 24):

> we can store session storage like that

store token should be like

```
 localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ token: token, username: username }));
```

**Store Session in to sessionStorage**

*You can store both string and array into session storage*

**String Ex.**

```
    let key = 'title'; 
    let value = 'session';
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Array Ex.**

```
    let key = 'user'; 
    let value = [{'name':'shail','email':'example@gmail.com'}];

    value = JSON.stringify(value);

    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Get stored session from sessionStorage by key**

```
const session = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

**Delete saved session from sessionStorage by key**

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
```

**Delete all saved sessions from sessionStorage**

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

2. store Local storage should be like

> Store items in to localStorage

*You can store both string and array into location storage*

**String Ex.**

```
 let key = 'title'; 
 let value = 'session';
 localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Array Ex.**

```
let key = 'user'; 
let value = [{'name':'shail','email':'example@gmail.com'}];

value = JSON.stringify(value);

localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Get stored items from localStorage by key**

```
const item = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

**Delete saved session from localStorage by key**

`localStorage.removeItem('key');`

**Delete all saved items from localStorage**

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: by both methods, we can access token by `this.sessionStorage.getItem('token')`, remove token by `this.sessionStorage.removeItem('token')`.

Answer (score 11):

As a general rule, the token should not be stored on the `localStorage` neither the `sessionStorage`. Both places are accessible from JS and the JS should not care about the authentication token.

IMHO The token should be stored on a cookie with the `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flag as suggested here: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: I agree with you, local storage is not secure enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

```
var userID = data.id;

localStorage.setItem('userID',JSON.stringify(userID));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[{"username":"sai","email":"sai@example.com,"}]
localStorage.setItem('logInArr', JSON.stringfy(arr))
```

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer to this question. Could you [edit] to add some explanation why your answer is a good one and help learners understand it. This will help you get reputation votes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best practice: https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage

I was use it in AngularJs, now with Angular2. Wery usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Bojan Kogoj's answer:

In your app.module.ts, add a new provider for storage.

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      { provide: Storage, useValue: localStorage }
   ],
   imports:[],
   declarations:[]
})
```

And then you can use DI to get it wherever you need it.

```
 @Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
 })
 export class StateService {
    constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`import { Injectable,OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
 export const localStorage = new OpaqueToken('localStorage');`

Place these lines in the top of the file, it should resolve the issue.