# Retain data on page reload in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

In my Angular 2 app, I pass in some data to a PageComponent from my HomeComponent which is then saved to a variable inside the PageComponent. Now when I refresh the page I need this data to be retained. Currently I am using session storage, but I was wondering if there is a better way to implement this.

Comment: use local storage instead of cookies. You will have lot of advantages over cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, There isn't a other way in this context. Once you refresh all the temporary memory is gone. As you said you are performing session-storage. You may continue with that. You may choose the below.

1. LocalStorage
2. Cookie
3. Session

Difference and importance: [How to store token in Local or Session Storage in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840457/how-to-store-token-in-local-or-session-storage-in-angular-2)

Comment: I would like to go with LocalStorage for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise you implement some server side framework and implement a database and store and retrieve data that way, it's a lot cleaner and much more reliable, session is a very dated way of doing things, at minimum I would use cookies so they at least persist a little more reliably.