# Session Storage in Angular 2 - Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

How to store the json value in session storage using angular2. I'm new to angular2 kindly do help.

below is my code:

```
.do(data => alert("All: " + alert(JSON.stringify(data))))
```

im getting json value in the alert. Now i need to store the value in session storage and it should be accessible in all over the application.
Below is my code but is it not working.

```
var EmpDetails = [data => JSON.stringify(data)];
EmpDetails.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')));
localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(EmpDetails));
alert(EmpDetails);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store token in Local or Session Storage in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840457/how-to-store-token-in-local-or-session-storage-in-angular-2)

Comment: how to store '.do(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data)))' in a variable @Antikhippe

Comment: .do(data => localStorage.setItem('session',JSON.stringify(data)))

Comment: thanks @Eliseo. but its returning null while getting value from this. `const session = localStorage.getItem('session');`

Comment: I am sure that the problem it's not here. Check in a navigator the localStore. You must see the "session" saved

Answer (score 6):

**You can store data to session or local storage. You can store both string and 
array into session**

> **Store in to  Session:**

**Use:** *import {SessionStorageService} from '../../sessionstorage.service';*

**Store string in session**

```
    let key: 'title'; 
    let value: 'session';
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Store array in session**

```
    let key: 'user'; 
    let value: [{'name':'any-name','email':'example@anymail.com'}];

    value = JSON.stringify(value);

    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Get stored session from sessionStorage by key**

```
const session = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

**Delete saved session from sessionStorage by key**

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
```

**Delete all saved sessions from sessionStorage**

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

> **Store in to localStorage**

*You can store both string and array into location storage*

**Use:** *import {LocalStorageService} from "../../localstorage.service";*

**Store string in local storage**

```
 let key: 'title'; 
    let value: 'session';
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Store array in local storage**

```
let key: 'user'; 
    let value: [{'name':'any-name','email':'example@anymail.com'}];

    value = JSON.stringify(value);

localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

**Get stored items from localStorage by key**

```
const item= localStorage .getItem('key');
```

**Delete saved session from localStorage by key**

`localStorage.removeItem('key'`);

**Delete all saved items from localStorage**

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: you forgot let data = localStorage.getItem("key"); this.key = JSON.parse(data);