# Set Jwt Token in Local Storage - Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I'm using `auth0/angular-jwt` library on branch v1.0 which supports `HttpInterceptor`.

Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authScheme: 'Bearer',
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        },
      }
    }),


I return from my backend side:
{
    "access_token": "token - I removed it for the example)",
    "expires_in": "2017-12-25T07:26:30Z",
    "id": "19a6609f-4ed9-4804-adad-a83ss670c7ba"
}
```

The problem is that the token isn't saved in `localStorage`. Have I missed something?

Comment: You are showing us how you are **getting** token, but where are your setting it?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840457/how-to-store-token-in-local-or-session-storage-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the token from the HTTP \ backend service you need to write it to local storage like below, where `result` equals the response in JSON from the server.

`localStorage.setItem ('token', result.token);`

I just covered this in a course yesterday [The Complete Angular Course](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-angular-master-class/learn/v4/overview) it's worth looking at, it covers authorization and authentication. It's a really good course and will help no end.